# I Need File System Help

Tags: 12.04, lts

There are four paper looking icons in the file system they all have a dark black arrows at the bottom.

Is it normal for them not to be in a folder?

If not how do I remove them?

Here's how they read :

1. initrd.img
2. initrd.img.old
3. vmlinuz
4. vmlinuz.old

Answer (score 0):

They are [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to Linux kernels and initial RAM disks. They are normal in Ubuntu. You should leave them alone.